# Подсчет количества элементов в результате запроса

Tags: алгоритм, postgresql, sql

Не до конца понял, как сделать следующее: у меня есть табличка с объектом "книга". Каждую книгу отмечают несколькими разделами (метками, как на hashcode.ru). Разделы хранятся в одной строке разделенные пробелами. Мне надо сделать запрос, в котором у заданного автора выведутся разделы и их количество. Как я понимаю, надо делать примерно так:

1. Делаем делаем запрос по таблице книг на совпадение по имени автора, в котором выбираем все разделы у книг. Примерно это выглядит так: `SELECT string_to_array(tags, " " FROM book WHERE author = 'Иван Иванов';`. Затем передать результат в `tags_chart`.
2. Затем реализуем ф-ю `tags_chart`. Это будет обычная pl/pgsql - функция.

Ее можно написать так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUCNTION tags_chart(SETOF character))
RETURNS SETOF record
AS '...'
LANGUAGE pl/pgsql;
```

Вопрос в том, как реализовать механизм подсчета количества элементов. Решение в лоб создать запись, метка - количество, и пройтись по всем элементам, при нахождении метки в записях увеличивать количество. Но, как мне кажется, это не верно. Тут сложность O(n^2). С условием того, что мне надо выбрать не все, а только `n` первых меток автора, ощущение, что задачу надо решать по другому.

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед - храните разделы не в строке, а в служебной таблице

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал немного по-другому (кстати, хотелось бы знать, лучше сделал или хуже).

Для начала напишем процедуру преобразования (тиснуто из интернета):

```
create or replace function unnest(anyarray)
returns setof anyelement 
language sql as $$ 
select $1[i] from generate_series(array_lower($1, 1), array_upper($1, 1)) as i;
$$;
```

Затем, используюя вложенный запрос, получим нужные данные:

```
SELECT count(*) as num, name FROM 
(SELECT unnest(string_to_array(tags, ' ')) AS name FROM book WHERE author = 'Иван Иванов') tag 
GROUP BY name ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 10;
```